# WCF service - Return int from "Method = 'DELETE'"

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, exception, http-delete

I'm trying to do some sort of exception control in my service (returning simple integers and handling these in the GUI), but I've stumbled upon a difficulty.

In all of my `POST`, and `PUT` I return either `1` or `-1` (depending on the exception I receive), but I can't seem to return an integer from my `DELETE` method.

This is my approach:

**IService.cs**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = "/logins/delete/{stringId}")]
int DeleteLogin(string stringId);
```

**Service.cs**

```
/// <summary>
/// Deletes the Login with the given stringId
/// </summary>
/// <param name="stringId"></param>
public int DeleteLogin(string stringId)
{
    try
    {
        var id = Int32.Parse(stringId);
        var dbLogin = DAO.HourRegInstance.Login.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
        DAO.HourRegInstance.Login.Remove(dbLogin);
        DAO.HourRegInstance.SaveChanges();
        return 1;
    } catch(Exception e){
        return -1;
    }
}
```

*Don't waste time explaining me to catch specific exceptions. This is simply the test environment*

**Ajax call**

```
 function deleteUser() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: baseAddress + "logins/delete/" + user.Id,
    }).done(function (code) {
        if (code === 1) {
            DevExpress.ui.notify('Your account has been deleted!', 'success', 3000);
            HourRegistrationApplication.app.navigate({
                view: "Login"
            })
        } else if (code === -1) {
            DevExpress.ui.notify('Something went wrong, please try again.', 'error', 3000);
            HourRegistrationApplication.app.navigate({
                view: "LoginProfile"
            })
        }
    }).error(function (err) {
        console.log(err);

        DevExpress.ui.notify('Something went wrong, please try again.', 'error', 3000);
        HourRegistrationApplication.app.navigate({
            view: "LoginProfile"
        })
    })
}
```

**This is what I get returned:**

[image]

Is there a way for me to return an integer from my `DELETE` method? Or is this simply just not possible?

Comment: Please include more information than just "it doesn't work". I see no WCF in there. What is the problem returning an int using WCF? Do you get errors?

Comment: @nvoigt Edited. I don't get any errors. the variable `code` is simply just something I don't quite understand (see main question)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve my problem on my own.

In the data annotation, I simply replaced this:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = "/logins/delete/{stringId}")]
```

With this:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/logins/delete/{stringId}")]
```

Basically just added the `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I just tried it myself and it works fine. Try using the `BodyStyle` Parameter at your `WebInvokeAttribute`. And set it to `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` this unwraps all your content and makes the server returning just the raw data..

Comment: No difference. Still not returning the integer

Comment: try setting the `dataType` Property for your ajax request to plain text and see what you get there. There should be something like `..DeleteLoginResult`, isn't it? And btw your `code` object result appears to be a html document..